# Allocate nodes from different partitions for each subjob

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to simulate a client-server interaction. For this, I'd like to use two different servers from the same cluster. Slurm traditionally allows us to this by requesting a set of nodes

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #SBATCH --job-name="test-script"
    #SBATCH -D .
    #SBATCH --output=./testlog/test-%j.out
    #SBATCH --error=./testlog/test-%j.err
    #SBATCH --nodes=3
    #SBATCH --exclusive
    #SBATCH --time=00:02:00
    #SBATCH --partition=a,b
LOG_FILES=${PWD}
    srun -lN1 -r 0 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Server-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Server-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_server.bash  &
    sleep 1
    srun -lN1 -r 1 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Client-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Client-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_client.bash &
    sleep 1
    srun -lN1 -r 2 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Client1-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Client1-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_client.bash &
```

This basically allows us to get two 3 different nodes on a combination of partition a and b.

`launch_client.bash` and `launch_server.bash` are fairly simple scripts doing this `ifconfig | grep 'inet'`

The question I have now is to figure out how to get resources from partition "a" for "server" and resources from partition "b" for "client".

This is my first attempt

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #SBATCH --job-name="test-script"
    #SBATCH -D .
    #SBATCH --output=./testlog/test-%j.out
    #SBATCH --error=./testlog/test-%j.err
    #SBATCH --nodes=3
    #SBATCH --exclusive
    #SBATCH --time=00:02:00
    #SBATCH --partition=a,b
LOG_FILES=${PWD}
    srun --partition=a -lN1 -r 0 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Server-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Server-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_server.bash  &
    sleep 1
    srun --partition=b -lN1 -r 1 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Client-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Client-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_client.bash &
    sleep 1
    srun --partition=b -lN1 -r 2 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Client1-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Client1-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_client.bash &
```

This, unfortunately, gets the resources arbitrarily from `a/b` and spawns the server/client also on `b`/`a` when it should be spawned only on `a`/`b`.

How do we get request precisely for a set of nodes from partition `a` and `b`?

Comment: After a big more digging, it seems like you can't actually get nodes from two different partitions. need to find another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the most elegant way, and will fail in at least one *main* scenario.

This is the launch script

```
#!/bin/bash
jid1=$(sbatch testscript2.bash)
jid1=$(echo $jid1 | awk '{print $4}')
jid2=$(sbatch --dependency=after:${jid1} testscript.bash)
```

This is the script for test_script2.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name="test-script2"
#SBATCH -D .
#SBATCH --output=./testlog/test1-%j.out
#SBATCH --error=./testlog/test1-%j.err
#SBATCH --time=00:02:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --partition=a

LOG_FILES=${PWD}

srun -lN1 -r 0 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Server-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Server-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_client.bash  & wait
```

This is the script for testscript.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name="test-script"
#SBATCH -D .
#SBATCH --output=./testlog/test-%j.out
#SBATCH --error=./testlog/test-%j.err
#SBATCH --time=00:02:00
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --partition=b

LOG_FILES=${PWD}

srun --partition=b -lN1 -r 0 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Client-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Client-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_client.bash &
sleep 1
srun --partition=b -lN1 -r 1 --output=${LOG_FILES}/'Client1-%j.out' --error=${LOG_FILES}/'Client1-%j.err' --unbuffered stdbuf --output=0 --error=0 ./launch_client.bash &
sleep 1
```

this will fail if `jid2` fails to get resources before `jid1` finishes or if it gets it `too late`